# The method is readDouble is undefined for the type

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pizza {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("what is the diameter of the pizza that you want?");
    double pizzadiameter = readDouble("Enter pizza diameter: ");
    System.out.println("The diameter of the pizza will be " + pizzadiameter + ".");
                         
  }
}
```

My problem is that `double pizzadiameter = readDouble("Enter pizza diameter: ");` (line 6) is giving me an error saying the method is undefined.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html). There is no method `readDouble` that takes a String as argument.

Comment: `the method is undefined` is a short and precise error message. You should have a look at how to accept user input. Most likely you will want to do the following: `double pizzadiameter =  input.nextDouble();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get the input  using `input.nextDouble`

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("what is the diameter of the pizza that you want?");
            double pizzadiameter = input.nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("The diameter of the pizza will be " + pizzadiameter + ".");
            
    }
```

Comment: Ah thank you, it worked :) sorry to bother everyone lol, I appreciate the help.